# Use ipython notebook to write a scraper or spider to download a couple of webpages

Tags: python, download, web-scraping, ipython, html

I am new to web scraping. We are asked to use iypthon notebook to write a scraper or spider to download a couple of webpages. This is what we got to in class, but I think there is an additional step I cannot figure out.

```
%pylab inline
import urllib
myUrl="http://www.google.com"
theSite=urllib.urlopen(myUrl).read()
import re
tags=re.findall('''<(.+?)>''',theSite,re.DOTALL)
print len(tags)

for i in range(100):
    print tags[]
```

Comment: What is the desired output? What result do you get currently?

Comment: I think that is what I am mainly confused about. this is the question "Use iPython notebook to write either a scraper of spider to download a couple of web pages (5 or so, this is for training purposes, you don’t need to go crazy), I don’t care what site." a little excerpt of my result

!doctype html
html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en"
head
meta content="Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking for." name="description"
meta content="noodp" name="robo

Comment: I propose that you ask your professor to specify in more detail, what output your code should deliver.